# Installed Python 3.12.1 on Mac Monterey (12.3.1), can find python3 but errors

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I am a newbie trying to figure out the issue with the python install.  I installed the pkg from python.org on my Mac. I did install it several times which maybe the cause of the issue.

When I try `python -V` or `python -version`, I get the error `zsh: command not found: python`

When I type in `python3`, I get the following result

```
Python 3.12.1 (v3.12.1:2305ca5144, Dec  7 2023, 17:23:38) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
```

When I run `which python3`, I get the expected result:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
```

So this might be an issue with `$PATH` (but I am not sure and just muddling around).
Running `echo $PATH`, I get the following result:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Is this the issue?

Overall, I am trying to troubleshoot the installation of another application that requires python3 and based on my investigation so far it's seems to be related to the `pip` command being unable to find the `pkg-config` executable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by more troubleshooting. It looks like, my installation of Python3 was good, but it required me to set the $PATH variable correct. Also, I was incorrect that PIP was part of the Python download app. So I had to install PIP3 and was able to resolve the outstanding issue.